# ERROR: yaml.parser.Parser Error: while parsing a block mapping in "./docker-compose.yml"

Tags: docker, docker-compose

ERROR: yaml.parser.Parser Error: while parsing a block mapping in "./docker-compose.yml", line 1, column 1

```yaml
services:
  wings:
    image: ghcr.io/pterodactyl/wings:latest
    restart: always
    networks:
      - wings0
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "2022:2022"
    tty: true
    environment:
      TZ: "UTC"
      WINGS_UID: 988
      WINGS_GID: 988
      WINGS_USERNAME: pterodactyl
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
      - "/var/lib/docker/containers/:/var/lib/docker/containers/"
      - "/etc/pterodactyl/:/etc/pterodactyl/"
      - "/var/lib/pterodactyl/:/var/lib/pterodactyl/"
      - "/var/log/pterodactyl/:/var/log/pterodactyl/"
      - "/tmp/pterodactyl/:/tmp/pterodactyl/"
      - "/etc/ssl/certs:/etc/ssl/certs:ro"
      # you may need /srv/daemon-data if you are upgrading from an old daemon
      #- "/srv/daemon-data/:/srv/daemon-data/"
      # Required for ssl if you use let's encrypt. uncomment to use.
      #- "/etc/letsencrypt/:/etc/letsencrypt/"
networks:
  wings0:
    name: wings0
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: "172.21.0.0/16"
    driver_opts:
      com.docker.network.bridge.name: wings0
```

This I've got the error above when I tried to run the script down with docker. I watched some videos on it but none of them helped.

Comment: some of the code is not in the snipet

Comment: The error implies a non-Docker-specific YAML syntax error; have you tried to run a YAML validator over the file?  It doesn't look obviously wrong as reproduced in the question.  Older versions of the Compose tool will need a `version:` line, and I'd recommend removing both `networks:` blocks, but neither of these are YAML syntax problems.

Comment: I would be nice to see the complete error, because I think that's not the full error what you mentioned in the title of question (I have tried your compose file and it works for me without any change).